Use Mutation in GraphQL with Chocolate
How can I solve the next error in GraphQL and C#, Query, Models, etc, works, but no Mutation, I don have any Idea for fixed it this, all code is correct but contnues ask me about Errors and about filds, you are free in your anwer or can create a new file can I need
HotChocolate.SchemaException: For more details look at the `Errors` property.

1. The object type `Mutation` has to at least define one field in order to be valid. (HotChocolate.Types.ObjectType<GraphQL.Mutation>)

Program.cs config file
builder.Services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddMutationConventions(applyToAllMutations: true)
    .AddMutationType<Mutation>()
    .AddQueryType<Query>()
    .RegisterService<IContext>()
    .AddFluentValidation();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapGraphQL();

Mutation file with mutation
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace api.core.GraphQL.Mutations;

public partial class Mutation
{
    [UseMutationConvention]
    public async Task<Response> Session([Service] IContext context, Request request)
    {
        return await new Handler(context).Handle(request);
    }
}

public class Handler(IContext context)
{
    public async Task<Response> Handle(Request request)
    {
        // if (appId == "") throw new Exception("`Session_APP_ID` hasn't been set.");
        // if (appCode == "") throw new Exception("`Session_APP_CODE` hasn't been set.");

        var sesion = await context.User.Where(item => item.IdUser == request.IdUser).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return new Response
        {
            User = (BeUser)sesion
        };
    }
}

Request and Response load without errors, but I just add mutation and the app its down.
How can I configure Mutation in C#?
Fixed code o added Fixed code o added
